# Specific racing game for Android

Tags: game

I am looking for a racing game that **MUST** have:

- turning,
- acceleration,
- breaking,
- hairpins,
- chicanes,
- either ai opponents or ghost driver,
- multiple sport style tracks with visible edge lines and actual 3D kerbs,
- non-arcade relatively realistic physics.

It **MAY** include more cool things like:

- great scenery,
- amazing sound,
- great ai,
- multiple real world tracks like Monza or Laguna Seca,
- championship mode,
- world players stats,
- multiplayer,
- tire degradation,
- free version,
- etc, but that all is optional.

Things that it must **NOT** have:

- no nitro,
- no attacking other cars,
- no jumping,
- no coin collection,
- no casual traffic on roads,
- no obstacles to destroy,
- no monsters or cartoon characters,
- no superpowers, magic bolts, rockets or bombs,
- no car upgrades or economy of any kind.
- not force me to update itself or any part more than once a year.

Basically I look for a game that is about RACING, braking points, racing lines, apexes, learning track, concentration, not a brainless amusement kind of game which are plenty on Play Store.

I knew exactly this kind of game for Windows CE, called Michael Schumacher Racing World Kart 1.6 (MSRWK). I just cannot believe that no matter how many racing games I try, and I try almost every one I can find, there is nothing even close. Also it is nearly impossible to keep track of all games, unless you are keen to spend days and record all your findings in the spreadsheet.

The best candidate I ever tried was Highway Rally, but it had nitros, cartoonish physics, and concrete blocks randomly littered around the track, probably authors intended it for fun.

EDIT

I do not need a racing simulator either, in a sense that I do not care about extremely detailed graphics (MSRWK had 300x200 pixel software rendered graphics), no car settings (MSRWK only allowed you to change the helmet color!), no multiple screens, no sun glare on every detail.

Michael Schumacher Racing World Kart:

[image: Michael Schumacher Racing World Kart]

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a racing *sim*, not just a normal game. Those games are common for PC and console because you can make setups that better emulate a real racing environment (multiple screens, car controls, beeeefy graphics). Android devices by and large aren't suited for something like this, but rather that "brainless amusement kind of game".

Real Racing 3 is probably the closest you're going to come for now. I suggest if you want a serious racing sim experience, you use a serious racing sim platform like consoles or PC.

Comment: Updated my answer. You misunderstand my intention, there is fun in racing, I am looking for a fun simple game, it is just another sort of fun, fun of truning, braking, going forward, not a fun of jumping, crashing, drifting, and not a fun of setting up your car and thinking how realistic is the experience, I do not care for simulators either.